# Effect where the photo appears inside the photo

Tags: photoshop-effects

I'm sure there's a proper name for this, but is there a technique for putting the picture that you're editing on a frame on the wall of the picture that you're editing? As if the photo was put on the wall before it was taken.
Whether or not it has a name, would be good to know if there's a special way of doing it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two different approaches for you. The first one is done manually in Photoshop, the second is more automatized using Illustrator also.

### Method A: Using Photoshop only

- Make sure the inside of the frame is transparent.

Now keep repeating this until the hole is filled:

- Alt + drag a copy of the bottom layer beneath itself.
- Press Ctrl/Cmd + T and scale the layer proportionally to fit the frame opening.

The result could look like this:

[image]

### Method B: Using Photoshop and Illustrator

- In Photoshop, make sure the inside of the frame is transparent and save the image, either as .psd or .tif with transparency.
- In Illustrator, create a web document with the same pixel dimensions as the image.
- Turn on *View > Pixel Preview*.
- Place the image.
- Use the *Appearance* panel while the image is selected to add a *Transform Effect*.
- Experiment with the *Scale* and *Move* settings until the image fits the frame. Increase the amount of *Copies* until the hole is filled.

This is my settings for this particular image:

[image]

<sub>The image is created by Kjpargeter - Freepik.com.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I searched for 'infinite recursion' and stumbled on the answer: [the Droste effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect), also referred to as [*mise en abyme.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme)

> A formal technique of placing a copy of an image within itself, often in a way that suggests an infinitely recurring sequence.

Comment: Not what OP is asking about. He's asking more about mock-ups where you have an environment (photograph of a billboard) and you can add your design on that billboard for presentation purposes.

Comment: @Alin huh? Dre's answer is exactly what I thought the person was asking as well. "A picture on a frame on the wall of the picture you're editing."

Comment: Thanks @Alin, that's the one! Doesn't seem an easy way to do it Photoshop though

Comment: Just for reference, GIMP 2.10 comes with the recursive-transform plugin, which is an implementation of the Droste effect (see [here](https://www.gimp.org/news/2018/03/26/gimp-2-10-0-rc1-released/)).