# How to Make An Almost Symmetric Image Seem Endless?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-editing, zoom

There are many almost symmetric images, such as: [image 1](https://archello.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/2014/02/10/01-PRISM-DESIGN.1506072655.482.jpg) or [image 2](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/28/20/81/282081b54866ad092632aa4c48af92b7.jpg)

What software do you suggest to use and how to make such images seem endless by copying part of the same image at its center?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These appear to be actual photographs of real building interiors, not manipulations. The second is Trinity College Library, Dublin.  For that level of realism, it would probably take something like Blender or a similar 3D modelling tool.  If that's not required then what you suggest sounds possible with Photoshop or any similar raster image editor.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You ask "What software do you suggest" but you've also tagged the question with `adobe-photoshop`. Photoshop would be a proper tool to use. I don't think there is any special trick. Just cut out a hole in the center and place a downscaled copy of the image behind. Spend some time getting the scale and position just right. Maybe use stamp tool or similar to make a seamless edge. I would answer this if I had a non-copyrighted image to use. You could perhaps find one? [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/107496) is similar.

Comment: @Wolff Thank you for your response. I thought Photoshop would be the right option, but I'd be interested in learning any software that you suggest to efficiently create this image. I found a CC and higher quality version of this second image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Long_Room_Interior%2C_Trinity_College_Dublin%2C_Ireland_-_Diliff.jpg I'd appreciate it if you give me some detailed guidance based on this image.

Answer (score 3):

This should work with any raster software which supports layers and layer masks, such as Photoshop, GIMP or Krita, etc

1. Take (or find) a suitable photo, and create a layer mask to remove its centre.
2. Duplicate the layer, and select the bottom layer. Scale it smaller.
3. Duplicate and merge the layers and move this to the bottom of the layer stack
4. Select the bottom layer and scale again. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until finished.
5. If there's a tiny white hole left at the end, make a layer underneath and fill with colour

[image]